# Scipy.optimize.minimize: Why is a global minimizing loss function much much slower than local one using Scipy minimize?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

I have two loss functions here to be minimized:

The first one is a **local** one, where:

min f1(x1),
min f2(x2),
min f3(x3),....
min fn(xn)

The other one is **global** one, where:

min f(x1,x2,...,xn) = f1(x1)+f2(x2)+...fn(xn)

For each local problem fi(x), I have 2 variables to be optimized, and I have 1000 local problems. Correspondingly, for the global problem, I have 2000 variables to be optimized. Surely the 2nd one has more parameters to be optimized, but since f1, f2, f3...fn are independent with each other, I hope they two should be comparable.

I use the scipy minimize function for optimization (scipy.optimize.minimize). But the 2nd one much much slower than the 1st one.

The only drawback of the global one, i think, is taking more gradients than it actually need to. For example, the gradient of x1 only comes from f1, but the global computes its gradient from f2, f3... fn, which is 0. Thus, making it slower. If that is the case, I do hope there would be some ways for acceleration.

BTW, since I later on need to add a global constraint to the optimization, this is why I must use the global loss function instead of the local one.

Comment: Hm, how many things do you need to compute for a local minimization (n minima)? How many things do you need to compute for a global minimization (all the extrema of an m-parameter function, which is far worse). This has nothing to do with scipy or programming, but is an inherent property of the problem you're solving...

Comment: yes, solving a function of 2000 parameters is **FAR** worse than solving 100 functions of 2 parameters (kind of obvious, isn't it?)

Comment: But as you can see, I'm just aggregating 1000 independent optimizations into one loss function, thus, I think these two scenarios should be comparable.

Comment: no. You've not given the math behind this much thought if you think that.

Comment: The only possibility is that the global one is taking more gradients than it actually need to, right? For example, the gradient of x1 only comes from f1, but the global computes its gradient from f2, f3... fn, which is 0. Thus, making it slower. Am I right? If that is the case, I do hope there would be some ways for acceleration.

Comment: Your 2000-argument function may be super simple, but SciPy doesn't know that. SciPy just sees a 2000-argument black box. It has to perform fully general 2000-variable minimization, not 1000 separate 2-variable optimization problems.

Comment: Thanks. That's also what I think. But is there any way that I can let scipy know it doesn't need so much unnecessary calculations? like putting some pre-calculated gradients to let it know most gradients are 0 actually?

Comment: Depending on the optimization method, you could pass it a Jacobian or Hessian function. I don't think sparse Jacobians or Hessians are supported, though.

Comment: While the general consensus (scipy does not recognize the problem-pattern) might be right, arguing with that does need a lot of assumptions (e.g. numerical vs. automatic differentiation; first-order vs. second-order opt; convex or non-convex; dense vs. sparse internals).

Answer (score 0):

I think your guess is correct that the amount of time that it takes more is because it needs to compute the gradients. Based on the description page for scipy.optimize.minimize (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html), it seems that the method computes the gradient numerically if you provide jac = False (optional and set to False by default).

> jac : bool or callable, optional
>
> Jacobian (gradient) of objective function. Only for CG, BFGS, Newton-CG, L-BFGS- B, TNC, SLSQP, dogleg, trust-ncg, trust-krylov, trust-region-exact. If jac is a Boolean and is True, fun is assumed to return the gradient along with the objective function. If False, the gradient will be estimated numerically. jac can also be a callable returning the gradient of the objective. In this case, it must accept the same arguments as fun.

Based on the above, you can set jac = True and then you should provide your function as a callable that returns function value as well as the gradients. This should speed up the process.
One other way is to write your own customizable minimizer as callable.

Comment: Indeed it seems a shame to me that scipy does not have a built-in minimizer that can handle this kind of dependence structure. When doing hundreds of thousands of minimisations that are all independent it would be very nice to be able to just do them all at once rather than waste so much time in the interpreter and in setting up the same minimisation over and over again.

Comment: I agree. But you should always consider that the general purpose optimizers are usually written for the most general case. And they are not supposed to be optimized for a specific structure or problem. On the other hand, it reduces the development time substantially if you want to try an idea real quick. But if you want to have an optimized solution, you need to change or abandon them for a better-optimized solution.